# MOVing between two memory addresses

Tags: assembly, x86, instructions, mov

I'm trying to learn assembly (so bear with me) and I'm getting a compile error on this line:

```
mov byte [t_last], [t_cur]
```

The error is

```
error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
```

I suspect that the cause of this error is simply that its not possible for a mov instruction to move between two memory addresses, but half an hour of googling and I haven't been able to confirm this - is this the case?

Also, assuming I'm right that means I need to use a register as an intermediate point for copying memory:

```
mov cl, [t_cur]
mov [t_last], cl
```

Whats the recommended register to use (or should I use the stack instead)?

Comment: sometimes is better go to the *source* instead of googling, here for example is Intel 64 & IA-32 instructions A-M, where you can see operand combinations for `mov`, http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/manual/253666.pdf

Comment: There're exceptions to the rule that an instruction cannot take two memory operands; see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510280/why-cant-mov-have-both-operands-as-memory-locations?lq=1#comment20229305_14510280).

Comment: Another question about multiple memory operands is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52573554/what-x86-instructions-take-two-or-more-memory-operands

Comment: Basically a duplicate of [Why isn't movl from memory to memory allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33794169) which explains some CPU-architecture / ISA-design reasons why not.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Your suspicion is correct, you can't move from memory to memory.

Any general-purpose register will do. Remember to PUSH the register if you are not sure what's inside it and to restore it back once done.

Comment: Is there any advantage to using a register over pushing the data itself onto the stack?

Comment: Pushing on and later popping from the stack adds two additional memory accesses.

Answer (score 7):

It's really simple in 16 bit, just do the following:

```
     push     di
     push     si
     push     cx
     mov      cx,(number of bytes to move)
     lea      di,(destination address)
     lea      si,(source address)
     rep      movsb
     pop      cx
     pop      si
     pop      di
```

Note: the pushes & pops are neceessary if you need to save the contents of the registers.

Comment: +1, since in some circumstances it's good to know all tools in your toolbox. rep movsb/movsw are 1 byte opcodes, IIRC

Comment: Depending on the architecture, you can use pusha instead of pushing all the registers individually and popa instead of popping them all.

Comment: This works in 32 and 64 bit as well, except it uses the registers for that bit system

Answer (score 7):

That's correct, x86 machine code can't encode an instruction with two *explicit* memory operands (arbitrary addresses specified in `[]`)

- [Why isn't movl from memory to memory allowed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33794169/why-isnt-movl-from-memory-to-memory-allowed)
- [What x86 instructions take two (or more) memory operands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52573554/what-x86-instructions-take-two-or-more-memory-operands/52574955#52574955)

> Whats the recommended register

**Any register you don't need to save/restore.**

In all the mainstream 32-bit and 64-bit calling conventions, EAX, ECX, and EDX are call-clobbered, so AL, CL, and DL are good choices.  For a byte or word copy, you typically want a `movzx` load into a 32-bit register, then an 8-bit or 16-bit store.  This avoids a false dependency on the old value of the register.  Only use a narrow 16 or 8-bit `mov` load if you actively *want* to merge into the low bits of another value.  x86's `movzx` is the analogue of instructions like ARM `ldrb`.

```
    movzx   ecx,  byte [rdi]       ; load CL, zero-extending into RCX
    mov    [rdi+10], cl
```

In 64-bit mode, SIL, DIL, r8b, r9b and so on are also fine choices, but require a REX prefix in the machine code for the store so there's a minor code-size reason to avoid them.

Generally avoid writing AH, BH, CH, or DH for performance reasons, unless you've read and understood the following links and any false dependencies or partial-register merging stalls aren't going to be a problem or happen at all in your code.

- [Why doesn't GCC use partial registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41573502/why-doesnt-gcc-use-partial-registers)
- [How exactly do partial registers on Haswell/Skylake perform? Writing AL seems to have a false dependency on RAX, and AH is inconsistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45660139/how-exactly-do-partial-registers-on-haswell-skylake-perform-writing-al-seems-to)

---

> (or should I use the stack instead)?

First of all, you can't push a single byte at all, so there's no way you could do a byte load / byte store from the stack.  For a word, dword, or qword (depending on CPU mode), you could `push [src]` / `pop [dst]`, but that's a lot slower than copying via a register.  It introduces an extra store/reload store-forwarding latency before the data can be read from the final destination, and takes more uops.

Unless somewhere on the stack *is* the desired destination and you can't optimize that local variable into a register, in which case `push [src]` is just fine to copy it there and allocate stack space for it.

**See https://agner.org/optimize/ and other x86 performance links in [the x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)**

Answer (score 6):

It is technically possible to move from memory to memory.

Try using **MOVS** (move string), and setting **[E]SI** and **[E]DI**, depending on whether
you want to transfer byte(s), word(s), etc.

```
    mov si, t_cur    ; Load SI with address of 't_cur'
    mov di, t_last   ; Load DI with address of 't_last'
    movsb            ; Move byte from [SI] to [DI]

    ; Some dummy data
    t_cur    db 0x9a ; DB tells NASM that we want to declare a byte
    t_last   db 0x7f ; (See above)
```

Note however that this is less efficient than executing **MOV** twice, but it does execute the copy in a single instruction.

Here's how **MOVS** should be used, and how it works:
https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movs:movsb:movsw:movsd:movsq

The instruction **MOVS** is almost never used on its own, and is for the most part used in conjunction with a **REP** prefix.

Modern CPUs have fairly efficient implementations of `rep movs` that is close to the speed of a loop using AVX vector load/store instructions.

```
    ; - Assuming that 't_src' and 't_dst' are valid pointers
    mov esi, t_src  ; Load ESI with the address of 't_src'
    mov edi, t_dst  ; Load EDI with the address of 't_dst'
    mov ecx, 48     ; Load [ER]CX with the count (let's say 48 dwords =   blocks)
    rep movsd       ; Repeat copying until ECX == 0
```

Logically the copy happens in 48 copies of 4-byte dword chunks, but really modern CPUs (fast strings / ERMSB) will use 16 or 32-*byte* chunks for efficiency.

This manual explains how **REP** should be used, and how it works:
https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rep:repe:repz:repne:repnz

Comment: +1 for explaining what `movsb` is and linking the manual, unlike other existing answers that propose `movs`.  I made some edits to your answer to *not* actually recommend doing this, because there's no benefit vs. mov-load + mov-store with a temp register like AL.  (Except maybe atomicity wrt. interrupts on a uniprocessor system, but that's a very specific use-case and not something that helps in general.)  But anyway, welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Comment: You also have to make sure the segment register DS and ES are set appropriately. That may not be the case if writing DOS programs that may use multiple segments where ES != DS. The move copies from DS:E(SI) to ES:E(DI). The OP didn't make mention of OS so one may not be ble to guarantee DS==ES

Answer (score 4):

There's also a MOVS command from moving data from memory to memory:

```
MOV SI, OFFSET variable1
MOV DI, OFFSET variable2
MOVS
```

Comment: Will work, but it requires extra care: you need to save si and di registers. I guess it's not worth it for copying one byte.

Comment: The string commands on x86 can be considered obsolete. Never use them. They are never faster than copying "by hand", but in most cases much slower.

Comment: @hirschhornsalz, sorry to necromance, but do you have any detailed info about the string commands being essentially obsolete?

Comment: string operations with rep are fast again thanks to new features like ERMS and FSRM. see clapdrop's answer below

Answer (score -1):

Just want to discuss "memory barrier" with you.
In c code

```
a = b;//Take data from b and puts it in a
```

would be assembled to

```
mov %eax, b # suppose %eax is used as the temp
mov a, %eax
```

The system cannot guarantee the atomicity of the assignment. That's why we need a rmb
(read barrier)

Comment: x86 can't atomically copy from memory to memory.  Barriers don't create atomicity, they only stop reordering (compile time or run-time or both, depending on the barrier).

Comment: @YuvalKeysar:  your edit left one bug unfixed (which I hadn't noticed before):  in AT&T syntax, destination comes 2nd.  This asm actually stores EAX into `b`, then loads EAX from `a`.  This answer just needs to be deleted, IMO, because the discussion about barriers is nonsense.