# Byte comparison asm invalid combination and opcodes

Tags: assembly, 64-bit, nasm, opcode

I'm using nasm in 64 bits and I get this error:

> error: invalid combination of opcode and operands

For this code:

```
cmp     BYTE [rdi + rax], BYTE [rsi + rax]
```

- `rdi` is my first argument (char*)
- `rsi` is my second argument (char *)
- `rax` is my cursor

What is wrong in this line? How should I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have two memory operands, you must move one to a register first. Also, this question has a hundred duplicates, but I can't find a good one. For example http://stackoverflow.com/q/14510280/555045 (but that's about `mov`)

Comment: Thanks! Which register should I use for that ? the third and fourth parameter's registers ? Sorry about duplicate post. It is very hard to find good answers.

Comment: Whichever register you want to use. Doesn't really matter. Obviously not a register whose value you want to keep.