# Why are Square Brackets used in LEA?

Tags: assembly, syntax, x86, memory-address, addressing-mode

In assembly, the square brackets `[]` seem to have the same meaning as `*` in *C* programming language.  They are used to dereference a pointer.
Dereferencing a pointer means going to refer to a specific memory location to read or write it.

So, it is quite logical to use square brackets in the case of a `MOV`.
But what is the logical reason why they also use it for LEA?

`LEA EAX, [EBP -4]`, looks like dereferencing a pointer, `EBP - 4`, to refer to the pointed memory location but it will not read the value contained in the location but rather the address.

I'm a little confused about this. Could you give me the right way to think about this?
Does `LEA` have any connection with the concept of dereferencing?
Clearly not intended as a memory reading, but mostly as referring to a location of memory not for its value, but for its address.
I wouldn't want this to become a philosophical question.

Comment: Related: [Using LEA on values that aren't addresses / pointers?](//stackoverflow.com/a/46597375)

Answer (score 5):

The `LEA` instruction is designed to look like a memory access instruction — so can perform all the [addressing modes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addressing_mode).  The difference, of course, as you're noting is that `LEA` loads the "effective address" rather than a memory value from that location.

Thus, `LEA` is similar to memory access operations, but specifically, in C terms, is taking the address — so like `&a[i]` in C.  Like in C with `&`, the result of `LEA` is always a pointer sized value rather than with real accesses where we can fetch/store a byte, word, etc..

Comment: I make an example in C ++.
int i = 10;
int ptr_i = &i;
int* ptr2_i = &*ptr_i
in this case ptr2_i will contain the address of i.
&*ptr_i is as if I were saying *ptr_i goes to dereference this pointer to refer to the memory location of i, but then due to & does not read the value of the location but the address. Is this correct ?

Comment: Yes, the & and * cancel out generally speaking (so do * and & cancel out, generally speaking), so the latter (`ptr2_i =`) is simply a direct assignment of (pointer) values with no memory dereferencing.  The former (`int ptr_i = &i`) could use the `lea` with `[rbp-n]` addressing mode to compute the address of `i`, with `i` as a local variable (it is on the stack, instead of in a register, since only memory variables have addresses whereas register variables don't.. taking `&i` basically forces `i` to be located in a memory location so that it has an obtainable address).